# Merging two sorted arrays. How to proceed if the second array is empty?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I wrote this code for merging two already sorted arrays in non-decreasing order.

The problem is the following:

Two `int` arrays `nums1` and `nums2` are sorted in *non-decreasing* order.
`nums1` has a length of **`m + n`** where **`m`** is a number of elements in `nums1`, and **`n`** is a number of elements in `nums2`. First elements of the *nums1* are filled with **`m`** number of integers and rest are filled with **zeros**.
Example `int[] nums1 ={1,2,4,0,0,0}` and `int[] nums2 = {2,5,6}`

I've traversed over `nums1` from the index `0` to `nums1.length` and placed an `if`* condition that will check whether an element of `nums2` is greater than an element in `nums1`. And this condition is `true` than this element will be moved to the right in *nums1* and element from `nums2` will replace this element.

Code:

```
class Solution {
public void merge(int[] nums1, int m, int[] nums2, int n) {
    int b =0;while (b<n){
    if(nums2.length==0)
    {
        for(int i =m;m<n;m++)
        {
            nums1[i]=0;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<m+n;i++)
    {
        if(nums1[i]>=nums2[b])
        {
           for(int j = m+n-1;j>=i;j--)//this for loop move every element right of ith element
           {
               nums1[j+1] = nums1[j];
           }
            nums1[i] = nums2[b];
            b++;
        }
        if(nums1[i]==0)
        {
            nums1[i] = nums2[b];
            b++;
        }
        
    }}
    
}}
```

**How do i proceed in case *n* = 0?**

**Constraints:**

```
   nums1.length == m + n
   nums2.length == n
   0 <= m, n <= 200
   1 <= m + n <= 200
   -109 <= nums1[i], nums2[j] <= 109
```

The problem is a **runtime exception** in case of `nums1 = {2,0}`  and `nums2= {1}`.

Comment: If the second array **is empty** (don't confuse this case with `null`) - simply return the **first**, there's nothing to merge.

Comment: @Alexander-Ivanchenko so should i first put a condition to check if either of the arrays is an empty array and proceed accordingly?

Comment: i did that but now some cases are coming that shows runtime error in case of `num1 = { 2,0} and ` `num2 ={1}`

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko Depends on the specified contract of the method.  If the client is expecting a new array containing the merged input, and not a reference to one of the existing arrays, this may cause unexpected failures later on.  For example, the client code modifies the returned array, believing that won't affect the original inputs... BOOM!

Comment: @JimGarrison Agree, at first, I thought too that a new array has to be created. But in the code above, the source array num1 is expected to be modified (it's a kind of coding challenge I guess).

Comment: If `nums2.length == 0` holds true, then `n = 0`, right? And the loop `for(int i = m; m<n; m++)` nested in this condition will not be executed.

Comment: Does your code work correctly when one array is shorter than the other? If it does, then you don't need to do anything special.  The "empty array" case is the same condition reached when one array is shorter, when you get to the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

I found **three approaches** on how to address this problem:

- Iterate through the array `nums1`, maintaining separate indices for both arrays. And for every encounter element in the `nums2` that is less than a current element in `nums1` shift the elements of the `nums1` starting from the current and assign the element from the `nums2` to the current position. In worse case when shifting has to be done for every element in the `nums2` (*all element in the second arrays smaller than the first value first array*) it'll perform in a quadratic time. I.e. **O(n * m)** (*that is the approach that OP tried to implement*). And also this solution is probably the simplest one.
- The second approach is to create an array of length identical to `nums1`. Iterate over the newly created array and populate it with the smallest values from the `nums1` and `nums2` for each step of the iteration. Then because `nums1` requires to be modified, all its contents should be replaced with elements from the new array. Time complexity of this approach is **O(n + m)** but memory consumption will be a bit greater.
- The third approach requires to allocate a new array of size `nums2.length` that will basically act like **queue** (array is used instead of collection in order to keep focus on the algorithm and make the solution more digestible for beginners). The idea of this algorithm to modify the `nums1` in place while iterating over it by choosing the smallest value for each iteration from `nums1`, `nums2`, and **queue**. The difference between this and previous approach is that array size will be smaller (because `nums1.length >= nums2.length`) and there will be no need to copy the contents of the **queue** to the `nums1`. I.e. it requires less operation and has a better memory consumption. Therefore, this approach is the **most performance-wise**.

The **first approach** (shifting the elements in the *first array* when a smaller value in the *second array* was encountered)

```
public static void merge(int[] nums1, int m, int[] nums2, int n) {
    if (nums2.length == 0) { // in this case there must be no trailing zeros in the NUMS1
        return;
    }
    // index for nums2
    int ind2 = 0;

    for (int ind1 = 0; ind1 < nums1.length && ind2 < nums2.length; ind1++) {
        if (nums1[ind1] <= nums2[ind2] && nums1[ind1] != 0) {
            continue; // no need change anything
        }
        // shifting all non-zero elements on the right from "prev" by 1 to the right
        int prev = nums1[ind1];
        for (int i = ind1 + 1; i < nums1.length && prev != 0; i++) {
            int next = nums1[i];
            nums1[i] = prev;
            prev = next;
        }
        nums1[ind1] = nums2[ind2++]; // assigning element from NUMS2 to the current position in NUMS1 and moving index of the NUMS2
    }
}
```

The **second approach** (to use an *intermediate array* of size `nums2.length`).

```
public static void merge(int[] nums1, int m, int[] nums2, int n) {
    if (nums2.length == 0) { // in this case there must be no trailing zeros in the NUMS1
        return;
    }
    // indices for nums1 and nums2
    int ind1 = 0;
    int ind2 = 0;

    int[] res = new int[nums1.length]; // result

    for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        if (ind2 == n ||  // index of the NUMS2 was exceeded
                (ind1 < m && nums1[ind1] < nums2[ind2])) { // index of the NUMS1 wasn't exceeded && value in the NUMS1 is less than value in the NUMS2
            res[i] = nums1[ind1++];
        }
        else {
            res[i] = nums2[ind2++];
        }
    }
    System.arraycopy(res, 0, nums1, 0, res.length);
}
```

The **third approach** (to use **queue**).

```
public static void merge(int[] nums1, int m, int[] nums2, int n) {
    if (nums2.length == 0) { // in this case there must be no trailing zeros in the NUMS1
        return;
    }
    // indices for nums1 and nums2
    int ind1 = 0;
    int ind2 = 0;

    int[] queue = new int[nums2.length]; // queue
    int put = 0; // queue indices
    int take = 0;

    for (;ind1 < nums1.length; ind1++) {
        if (take < queue.length && queue[take] != 0 && // index of the QUEUE wasn't exceeded && value in the QUEUE is NOT zero
                ((ind2 == n || nums2[ind2] > queue[take]) // index of the NUMS2 was exceeded || value in the queue is less than value in the NUMS2
                        && (ind1 >= m || nums1[ind1] > queue[take]))) { // value in the NUMS1 is zero (range M of non-zero values was exceeded) || value in the queue is less than value in the NUMS1
            
            if (ind1 < m) { // value in the NUMS1 is NOT zero and therefor has to be stored in QUEUE
                queue[put] = nums1[ind1]; // making a copy of the element && moving put index of the QUEUE index to the right
                put = ++put % queue.length;
            }
            // assigning value from the QUEUE && moving take of the QUEUE index to the right
            nums1[ind1] = queue[take];
            take = ++take % queue.length;
        }
        else if (ind2 < n && // index of the NUMS2 was exceeded
                (ind1 >= m || nums1[ind1] > nums2[ind2]) && // value in the NUMS1 is a trailing zero || value in the NUMS2 is less than value in the NUMS1
                (take == queue.length || // position in the QUEUE is illegal ||
                        queue[take] == 0 || queue[take] > nums2[ind2])) { // value in the QUEUE is zero || value in NUMS2 is the smallest
            // making a copy of the element && moving put index of the QUEUE index to the right
            queue[put] = nums1[ind1];
            put = ++put % queue.length;
            // assigning value from the NUMS2 to the element in NUMS1 && moving NUMS2 index to the right
            nums1[ind1] = nums2[ind2++];
        }
    }
}
```

**main()**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] nums1 ={1,2,4,0,0,0};
    int[] nums2 = {2,5,6};
    merge(nums1, nums1.length - nums2.length, nums2, nums2.length);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums1));

    nums1 = new int[]{2,0};
    nums2 = new int[]{1};
    merge(nums1, nums1.length - nums2.length, nums2, nums2.length);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums1));
}
```

**output** (for all versions)

```
[1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2]
```

**Note:**

- Condition `if (nums2.length == 0)` at the beginning of each implementation will terminate the method execution if the second array is empty.
- This statement `System.arraycopy(res, 0, nums1, 0, res.length);` in the implementation which utilizes an intermediate array is used to copy the contents of this array to `nums1`. The same result can be achieved by replacing [**`System.arraycopy()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,int,java.lang.Object,int,int)) with the following `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums1.length; i++) {
    nums[i] = res[i];
}
```